# When should I not use the Java Shortcut Operator &

Tags: java, shortcut, bitwise-operators

My understanding is that when using && as an mathematical operation in Java, if the LHS (Left Hand Side) of an evaluation fails, the right hand side will not be checked, so.

```
false && getName();
```

getName() would never be called as the LHS has already failed.

```
false & getName();
```

When would I ever want to check the RHS if I know the LHS has failed?  Surely any dependency on the RHS evaluation being ran would be bad coding practice?

Thank you

Comment: & _isn't_ a shortcut operator. "Short circuit evaluation" is the term usually applied to the way && and || work, but not to & or |.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the reason for `&` and `&&` is not, that one evaluates the right side and the other doesn't.

- `&` is a **bitwise operator**, which makes a bitwise AND of the two values. It returns a value.

  Theoretically, if all bits of the left side are 0 (as is the case for `false`), the right side must not neccessarily be evaluated. I guess it's a design decision that it **is** evaluated in every case. In the simple cases, it is faster than checking if the left side is 0.
- `&&` is a **conditional logical operator**, which takes two booleans and returns a boolean (that is `true` if and only if both sides are `true`).

  The same applies here, if the left side is `false`, we don't need to check the right side. Here the decision was taken to skip the evaluation of the right side in that case.

And to answer your last question (when would you want to evaluate the RHS if the LHS has failed), there are some scenarios where it can be ok. However, in any case it is possible to prevent these situations (see [jocelyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135982/1137043) for a good way to make sure that both expressions are evaluated) without loosing readability. In fact, I think jocelyn's way is more readable than `if (exprA() & exprB()) { ... }`.

Personally I never use `&` unless I really need a bitwise AND.

Comment: & applied to boolean values is a boolean operator, just like &&. It is a bitwise (not "binary") operator only when applied to numeric values. A boolean has no bit-level representation in Java.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the correction on the terminology. For the boolean: You can view it as a single bit in which case it would fit nicely into the definition.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are right, the [JLS, 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) makes a distinction between all-boolean expressions (which makes the "type of the bitwise operator expression boolean") and everything else (which makes the "type of the bitwise operator expression convertible"). But it is still unconditional (both sides are evaluated).

Comment: The error in the answer is not merely terminological. The first sentence is false; the *only* difference between `&` and `&&` when applied to boolean operators (which is what the question is about) is that one always evaluates the right-hand operator and the other doesn't if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> When should I not use the Java Shortcut Operator &

That's a strange question.  The best answer I can think of is that you should not use it if you DO want the short-circuit behaviour of `&&`.  (And that is most of the time ...)

> Surely any dependency on the RHS evaluation being ran would be bad coding practice?

I disagree.  That is tantamount to saying that side-effects are bad coding practice.

I will grant you that you rarely need to use `&` in boolean expressions, but that does not make it bad practice to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it would be bad practice to rely on the call of a RHS. If you need it to be called each time, call it before, store the result and use it in your comparaison expression.

```
if (false && getresult()) {

}
```

becomes

```
Boolean result = getresult();
if (false && result) {

}
```

Comment: or u can just put it in d left as:
if(result && false)

Comment: assuming he wanted both args to be executed ;)

Comment: @vedant1811 Well, this would just turn around the problem, but not solve it. Now the other expression is just evaluated conditionally...

Answer (score 1):

It is used in bitwise ANDing

for example

```
int i = 3; // 11 - binary
int j = 7; / 111 - binary
int k = i &j; // 11 & 111 = 11 = 3 (decimal)
```

basically & does logical ANDing so if you want to evaluate both the condition and then AND them then you could use

Answer (score 1):

Another typical case of use is you want to check both computed conditions:

```
if(++i < 0 & ++j < 0)
```

In this example regardless of the value of `i` `j` increases.

Bear in mind that this is achievable with another methods.  It saves you a couple of lines of code. Also as a  language  is nice to give the   chance of  evaluate both. Otherwise someone could ask why I cannot.