# what is the difference between '&' and '&&' in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [& vs && and | vs ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/vs-and-vs)
>   [What are the cases in which it is better to use unconditional AND (& instead of &&)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411907/what-are-the-cases-in-which-it-is-better-to-use-unconditional-and-instead-of)

While checking for the simple AND condition, i can use '&' and '&&'. It works fine with '&' and as well as '&&'. Is there any difference between those two.

sample code:

```
if(sample!=null & sample.size())
if(sample!=null && sample.size()
```

Comment: Your first line of code can throw a NullPointerException, but the second can't. That's the essential difference.

Answer (score 2):

The first version (&) always evaluates both arguments.
The second version (&&) evaluates the second argument only if the first argument has been evaluated to TRUE.

Same applies to the OR operator: there is | and ||. 
The (||) evaluates the second argument only if the first argument has been evaluated to FALSE.

Comment: With the exception that the OR operator evaluates the second argument only if the first argument has been evaluated to *false*.

Comment: Thanks @maba, the answer is updated

Answer (score 1):

first expression check both sides, second expression checks 2nd side only if 1st is true.

Answer (score 1):

It evaluates both the left hand side and the right with just a singular &, even if the last hand side is false.

See my question below for the finer details...

[When should I not use the Java Shortcut Operator &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135715/when-should-i-not-use-the-java-shortcut-operator)

Answer (score 1):

```
'&' for bit wise 'AND'
'&&' is for Logical 'AND'
```

Comment: Your statement is false and misleading. `&` is for both logical and bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(sample!=null & sample.size())
```

Here if first condition is not satisfied then also it will check next condition.

```
if(sample!=null && sample.size())
```

Here if first condition is not satisfied then also it will `not` check next condition.

Answer (score 1):

The && is a short-circuit operator meaning that if sample is null in your example, it will stop and not evaluate the second condition.

On the other side, the & is not short-circuit and will evaluate sample.size() even if sample is null. Of course in this case it will throw `NullPointerException`, but in the short-circuit case it won't.